# Descriptive complexity of communication complexity classes

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, lo.logic, communication-complexity

It is well known that some major complexity classes, like P or NP, admit a full logical characterization (e.g NP = existential 2nd order logic by Fagin's theorem). On the other hand, one can also define complexity classes in communication complexity (where P = problems solvable with poly(logN) communication etc. - see [Complexity classes in communication complexity theory](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1382962) for more).

My question is - are any descriptive complexity characterizations known for communication complexity classes (or do any such results from standard complexity classes transfer to communication setting easily)?

Comment: You may want to limit the computational power of the parties, which is not done in the usual communication complexity models.